# How to use UITableViewCell's accessoryButton as anchor for a Popover

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uipopover

I tried to use the `accessoryButton` of the UITableViewCell as the anchor of a Popover, but couldn't connect it using the storyboard. Programmatically I tried using the `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith` function, this didn't work either. How can I connect it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class is subclass of `UITableViewController` then use:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```

Check example code:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.detailButton
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
}
```

And if it's a subclass of `UIViewController` then you don't need `override` before that method so it will be:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```

And don't forget to connect `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` of your table view with your `ViewController` in this case.

Comment: the link is broken